# What is the correct pentalobe screwdriver size for a Macbook Air Model A1370?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

I think it is [1.2 mm based on results returned by eBay](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=pentalobe%20screwdriver%20macbook%20air&_sop=15), however, it would be nice if someone could confirm that this is the correct size and not the 0.8 mm

[Macbook Air MacBookAir4,1 (11-inch, Mid 2011)](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/specs/macbook-air-core-i5-1.6-11-mid-2011-specs.html)

The goal is to remove the outer-lower casing (pentalobe screws) as well as the SSD screw (unknown screw type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on information from iFixit, you need a [P5 Pentalobe Screwdriver](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Tools/P5-Pentalobe-Screwdriver-Retina-MacBook-Pro-and-Air/IF145-090?o=6), which is 1.2mm, as shown in this [MacBook Air 11" Mid 2011 Solid-State Drive Replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+11-Inch+Mid+2011+Solid-State+Drive+Replacement/6317) guide to remove the lower case.

You need a T5 Torx driver for the SSD.